# Android Studio 3.2.1 Build number AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338 could not start firebase assistant

Tags: android-studio

after upgrade the android studio to 3.2.1 i could not open the firebase assistant. i already uninstall and re-install it still no luck and the error message show when start firebase assistant

```
null
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.io.InputStream.<init>(InputStream.java:45)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:123)
at com.android.tools.idea.util.PropertiesFiles.getProperties(PropertiesFiles.java:40)
```